# navigating to other user's profile (laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I want that a login user can goto other user's profile pages where all his posts and other stuff is displayed.

what i tried is given below:

my route:

```
Route::get('/myplace/{username}' , [

        'uses' => 'PostController@getmyplace' ,

        'as' => 'myplace' ,

        'middleware' => 'auth:web'

]);
```

PostController:

```
public function getmyplace($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
    if(!$user)
        abort(404);

    $posts=Post::where(function($query){
         $query->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
            ->orWhereIn('user_id',Auth::user()->friends()->lists('id')
                );
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();

    $accounts=Account::orderBy('updated_at','desc')->limit(1)->get();

    return view('myplace',['user'=>$user,'posts'=>$posts,'accounts'=>$accounts]);
}
```

my view:

```
> @if (!$posts->count())
>         <p>{{$user->getNameOrUsername() }} hasn't posted anything, yet.</p>
>       @else
>         @foreach ($posts as $post)
>         @if(Auth::user()== $post->user)
> 
> <div class="panel panel-default">
>        <div class="panel-heading">
>        <div class="row">
>          <section class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">   <img id="imagesize2" src="images/g.jpg" class="img-circle" data-action="zoom"/></img>   
> </section>    <section class="col-md-5 col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-5">   
> <a id="alink13" href=""><h5
> id="alink14">{{$post->user->getNameOrUsername() }}</h5></a>
>      <p> on {{$post->created_at}} </p>    </section> 
>        </div> 
>        <div class="panel-content">
>        <div class="row" id="fetch">
>        <section class="col-md-12" data-postid="{{ $post->id }}">
>        <p id="post">{{$post->body}}</p>  
>        <div class="interaction" >
>        @if(Auth::user()==$post->user)
>        <a  href="" class="edit">Edit</a>
>        <a id="remove2" href="{{route('post.delete',['post_id' => $post->id])}}">Delete</a>
>        @endif
>        </div>
>           </section>
>        </div>
>        </div>
```

I passed the username parameter but that didn't gave the desired output.

Anything i need to provide just tell me.

Comment: what error you get? what you wanted to get and what you getting?

Comment: @AmirBar i want that when i goto someone's profile ,the content (here posts) of  that user is displayed. what i am getting is -> the content of logged in user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
$query->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
        ->orWhereIn('user_id',Auth::user()->friends()->lists('id')
            );
```

Your query is selecting data for Auth::user() instead of $user

```
$posts=Post::where(function($query) use ($user) {
     $query->where('user_id',$user->id)
        ->orWhereIn('user_id',$user->friends()->lists('id')
            );
})
->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

**EDIT** add **use ($user)** when declaring the anonymous function

Also you could remove the query if you have setup eloquent relations correctly.

```
$posts = $user->posts; // example
```

**EDIT 2** remove

```
@if(Auth::user()== $post->user)
```

You are selecting posts (in your controller) that DONT belongt to you. So don't check they belong to you in the view.

**EDIT 3**

For details have a look into the discussion. The current state is that actually another reference to a user is needed in the posts table. This reference defines on whoms "profile" the post as made on. Therefore it could be called **target_id** and references id on users table.

In a next step the route has to be changed so that a user id is passed (could also be passed in the request body ofcourse) e.g.

```
/user/{id}/profile
```

The controller then takes the passed $id parameter as target_id and the current user (Auth::user()) as user_id (creator of the post)

Finally the query can be adapted to actually select every post of the user himself + every post where he is the target

```
$posts=Post::where(function($query) use ($user) {
     $query->where('user_id',$user->id)
        ->orWhere('target_id',$user->id);
})
->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

Ofcourse the $user needs to be selected in the different requets and routing and internal redirects need to be adapted with regards to the changes.

Comment: Oh this is due to the anonymous function just add " use ($user) " to the function, i ll update my answer in a second | Now Added

Comment: i think something need to be changed in my view where i have used Auth

Comment: well you will for sure need to remove this @if(Auth::user()== $post->user) - I will update my answer again

Comment: I see that you have added the if check two times - it makes sense in the bottom part since you display the edit, but it seems the upper one is wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121231/discussion-between-yash-chaudhary-and-frank-provost).